# SDK Manager Android Studio OS X

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

How do you open SDK Manager on the latest Android Studio in OS X? It appears grayed out in the initial screen and it seems I don't have any SDK installed...

Answer (score 2):

Close all open projects so you get the opening screen.

Choose Configure -> Project-Default -> Project Structure

Then set the path to your SDK and JDK, respectively.

Mine are:

SDK: /Users//Development/android-sdk

JDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home

If you are on OSX, your JDK might be similar, your SDK will be wherever you put it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the SDK doesn't come with Android Studio, you have to install it manually. 
You can use brew with `brew install android-sdk` and then you can open it via `android` (All done in the terminal)

Comment: I'm sure it does come installed!

Comment: Yes, now it does. But back then when I wrote the answer it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found that the `android` binary was missing from the Studio.

So I downloaded the SDK, and moved it in.

Path is as given by @Cory, `/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk`